# How can write AES decrption in Jemeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm trying to write Aes decryption in jmeter but I am getting error

```
2020-11-03 18:14:22,612 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2020-11-03 18:14:22,612 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-11-03 18:14:22,613 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2020-11-03 18:14:22,758 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Api-1,Api2 and payment for widget creation 
2020-11-03 18:14:22,758 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Api-1,Api2 and payment for widget creation .
2020-11-03 18:14:22,758 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2020-11-03 18:14:22,758 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2020-11-03 18:14:22,771 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2020-11-03 18:14:22,771 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2020-11-03 18:14:22,772 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Api-1,Api2 and payment for widget creation  1-1
2020-11-03 18:14:22,775 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.security.InvalidKeyException;  import java.security.KeyFactory; impo . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation KeyFactory.getInstance
2020-11-03 18:14:22,775 WARN o.a.j.m.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.security.InvalidKeyException;  import java.security.KeyFactory; impo . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation KeyFactory.getInstance
2020-11-03 18:14:22,989 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.security.InvalidKeyException;  import java.security.KeyFactory; impo . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation KeyFactory.getInstance
2020-11-03 18:14:22,989 WARN o.a.j.m.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.security.InvalidKeyException;  import java.security.KeyFactory; impo . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation KeyFactory.getInstance
2020-11-03 18:14:23,036 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Api-1,Api2 and payment for widget creation  1-1
2020-11-03 18:14:23,037 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Api-1,Api2 and payment for widget creation  1-1
2020-11-03 18:14:23,038 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2020-11-03 18:14:23,039 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

and here is my solutions

```
 import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
    
    import java.security.KeyFactory;
    import java.security.KeyPair;
    import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.PrivateKey;
    import java.security.PublicKey;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
    import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.util.Base64;
    import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    
    
    String accessToken = "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";
    
    String data = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        PublicKey publicKey = null;
    
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(accessToken.getBytes()));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("AES");
        publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
                    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            byte[] bytes =  cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    
            
    byte[] dString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytes);
    vars.put("Authorization","Bearer "+dString);
    log.info("key = " + dString);
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The problematic line is:

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("AES");
```

as there is no such algorithm for the KeyFactory, the [possible values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyFactory) are:

- DiffieHellman
- DSA
- RSA
- RSASSA-PSS
- EC

Also [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for explanation and example usage

If you have to continue with Beanshell - consider adding `debug();` statement to the beginning of your test or putting your code in [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

```
try {
    //your code here
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    log.info("Something wrong", ex);
}
```

this way you will be able to see the root cause in the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)